# Resgen command is not working in post build event of project

Tags: resgen

This command is not working in post build event of project:

> resgen "$(ProjectDir)SpectrumLite_en-US.txt" "$(ProjectDir)"

Error message in output window is:

> 'resgen' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

That command successfully run on Visual Studio command prompt but neither in cmd nor post build event.